# C# task async await smart card - UI thread blocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await, smartcard

I'm new to C#, and I'm trying to use task async await for a WinsForm GUI. I've read so many tutorials about it, but all of them implement tasks differently. Some tasks use functions, and others just put the code in to execute. Some use Task.Run() or just await. Furthermore, all the examples I've seen are of functions that are included in the UI class. I'm trying to run functions that are in classes that are within my UI. I'm just really confused now, and don't know what's right/wrong.

What I'm trying to do is write a file to an EEPROM, using the SpringCard API/ PC/SC library. I parse the file into packets and write it to the smart card. I also want to update a status label and progress bar. A lot of things can go wrong. I have flags set in the smart card, and right now I just a while loop running until it reads a certain flag, which will obviously stall the program if it's forever waiting for a flag.

I guess I'm just confused about how to set it up. Help. I've tried using Tasks. Here is my code so far.

```
/* Initialize open file dialog */
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
            ofd.Filter = "BIN Files (.bin)|*.bin|HEX Files (.hex)|*.hex";
            ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:";
            ofd.Title = "Select File";

            //Check open file dialog result
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (shade != null)
                {
                    shade.Dispose();
                    shade = null;
                }
                return;
            }

            //progform.Show();
            Progress<string> progress = new Progress<string>();
            file = new ATAC_File(ofd.FileName);

            try
            {
                cardchannel.DisconnectReset();
                Task upgrade = upgradeASYNC();

                if(cardchannel.Connect())
                {
                    await upgrade;
                }
                else
                {
                    add_log_text("Connection to the card failed");

                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to the card in the reader : please check that you don't have another application running in background that tries to work with the smartcards in the same time");
                    if (shade != null)
                    {
                        shade.Dispose();
                        shade = null;
                    }

                    cardchannel = null;
                }
        }


    private async Task upgradeASYNC()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int totalpackets = 0;

            add_log_text("Parsing file into packets.");
            totalpackets = file.parseFile();

            /*progress.Report(new MyTaskProgressReport
            {
                CurrentProgressAmount = i,
                TotalProgressAmount = totalpackets,
                CurrentProgressMessage = "Sending upgrade file..."
            });*/

            ST_EEPROMM24LR64ER chip = new ST_EEPROMM24LR64ER(this, cardchannel, file, EEPROM.DONOTHING);

            bool writefile = chip.WriteFileASYNC();
            if(writefile)
            {
                add_log_text("WRITE FILE OK.");
            }
            else
            {
                add_log_text("WRITE FILE BAD.");
            }

        }
```

In the file class:

```
public int parseFile()
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(filename);

            int readbytecount = 0;
            int packetcount = 0;
            int numofbytesleft = 0;
            byte[] hash = new byte[4];
            byte[] packetinfo = new byte[4];
            byte[] filechunk = null;

            /* Read file until all file bytes read */
            while (size_int > readbytecount)
            {
                //Initialize packet array
                filechunk = new byte[MAXDATASIZE];

                //read into byte array of max write size
                if (packetcount < numoffullpackets)
                {
                    //Initialize packet info array
                    packetinfo[0] = (byte)((size_int + 1) % 0x0100); //packetcountlo
                    packetinfo[1] = (byte)((size_int + 1) / 0x0100); //packetcounthi
                    packetinfo[2] = (byte)((packetcount + 1) / 0x0100); //packetcounthi
                    packetinfo[3] = (byte)((packetcount + 1) % 0x0100); //packetcountlo

                    //read bytes from file into packet array
                    bytesread = br.Read(filechunk, 0, MAXDATASIZE);

                    //add number of bytes read to readbytecount
                    readbytecount += bytesread;
                }
                //read EOF into byte array of size smaller than max write size
                else if (packetcount == numoffullpackets)
                {
                    //find out how many bytes left to read
                    numofbytesleft = size_int - (MAXDATASIZE * numoffullpackets);

                    //Initialize packet info array
                    packetinfo[0] = (byte)((size_int + 1) / 0x0100); //packetcounthi
                    packetinfo[1] = (byte)((size_int + 1) % 0x0100); //packetcountlo
                    packetinfo[2] = (byte)((packetcount + 1) / 0x0100); //packetcounthi
                    packetinfo[3] = (byte)((packetcount + 1) % 0x0100); //packetcountlo

                    //Initialize array and add byte padding, MAXWRITESIZE-4 because the other 4 bytes will be added when we append the CRC
                    //filechunk = new byte[numofbytesleft];
                    for (int j = 0; j < numofbytesleft; j++)
                    {
                        //read byte from file
                        filechunk[j] = br.ReadByte();

                        //add number of bytes read to readbytecount
                        readbytecount++;
                    }

                    for (int j = numofbytesleft; j < MAXDATASIZE; j++)
                    {
                        filechunk[j] = 0xFF;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                }

                //calculate crc32 on byte array
                int i = 0;
                foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(filechunk))
                {
                    hash[i++] = b;
                }

                //Append hash to filechunk to create new byte array named chunk
                byte[] chunk = new byte[MAXWRITESIZE];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(packetinfo, 0, chunk, 0, packetinfo.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(filechunk, 0, chunk, packetinfo.Length, filechunk.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(hash, 0, chunk, (packetinfo.Length + filechunk.Length), hash.Length);

                //Add chunk to byte array list
                packetcount++;
                PacketBYTE.Add(chunk);
            }

            parseCMD();

            return PacketBYTE.Count;
        }
```

In the EEPROM class:

```
public bool WriteFileASYNC()
    {
        int blocknum = ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFBN_RFstartwrite;
        byte[] response = null;
        CAPDU[] EEPROMcmd = null;
        int packetCount = 0;

        log("ATTEMPT: Read response funct flag.");
            do
            {
                StopRF();
                Thread.SpinWait(100);
                StartRF();
                log("ATTEMPT: Write function flag.");
                while (!WriteFlag(ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFBN_functflag, EEPROM.UPLOADAPP)) ;
            } while (ReadFunctFlag(ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFBN_responseflag, 0) != EEPROM.UPLOADAPP);  

            for (int EEPROMcount = 0; EEPROMcount < file.CmdBYTE.Count; EEPROMcount++)
            {
                string temp = "ATTEMPT: Write EEPROM #" + EEPROMcount.ToString();
                log(temp);
                EEPROMcmd = file.CmdBYTE[EEPROMcount];

                while (EEPROMcmd[blocknum] != null)
                {
                    if (blocknum % 32 == 0)
                    {
                        string tempp = "ATTEMPT: Write packet #" + packetCount.ToString();
                        log("ATTEMPT: Write packet #");
                        packetCount++;
                    }

                    do
                    {
                        response = WriteBinaryASYNC(EEPROMcmd[blocknum]);
                    } while (response == null);

                    blocknum++;
                }

                log("ATTEMPT: Write packet flag.");
                while (!WriteFlag(ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFBN_packetflag, ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFflag)) ;

                log("ATTEMPT: Write packet flag.");
                do
                {
                    StopRF();
                    Thread.SpinWait(300);
                    StartRF();

                } while (!ReadFlag(ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFBN_packetresponseflag, ((blocknum/32) - 1)*(EEPROMcount+1)));

                blocknum = ATAC_CONSTANTS.RFBN_RFstartwrite;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: The `upgradeASYNC` method causes a warning, telling you what's wrong. Don't ignore warnings, especially when your code doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I also suspect that this line 'bool writefile = chip.WriteFileASYNC();' is not doing much, and to get the result you probably need to await that method.  If it is an async method, it will return immediately, so what is the result of writefile?

Comment: Sorry I'm stepping into the middle of this and all I can see are svick's and stevethethread's comments. what is going on?

Comment: @stevethethread the chip.writefileasync() does everything!! it writes the entire file to the eeprom. it takes the longest.

Comment: @user2840469 What's going on is that the comment I replied to was deleted, so now I also deleted my reply.

Comment: As you say, the call to WriteFileAsync takes the longest.  Thats the whole point.  When you call await on that, execution is returned to the calling thread and does not block. The code after the await is only executed once the async work has completed.  In TPL terms its the equivalent of having a Continuation Task.

Answer (score -1):

Tasks are threads.

When you write this:

```
Task upgrade = upgradeASYNC();
```

you are simply executing upgradeASYNC in a new thread.

When you write this:

```
 await upgrade;
```

You are only waiting for the new thread to finish (before going to the next instruction).

And this method

```
private async Task upgradeASYNC()
```

returns a Task object only because you add the async keyword. But in the body of this method there is no await. So it just runs synchronously, like any thread job.

I don't have time to rewrite your code, i let that to another stackoverflow user. You should learn and work harder ;)

Comment: “Tasks are threads.” That's very wrong, especially when it comes to asynchronous methods. For a very detailed description, see Stephen Cleary's article [*There Is No Thread*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: You should read the article, its title is here to grab your eyes. "If the async operation is pure, then there is no thread.". This is true and not true: when a Task is created, it is run in a thread (exising or not). In this thread if the code awaits for an async op, then the thread is freed (and "there is no thread") for the duration of the op (using windows io completion ports).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I'm saying that your first sentence is very wrong. Tasks are *not* threads.

Comment: Yes they are. Intelligent lightweight cachable reusable threads.

Comment: So when you say “thread” you mean something entirely different from `System.Threading.Thread` or the underlying OS thread? If that's the case, I think you should make that very clear.

Comment: The Task framework is based on .net threads which are based on os threads. A Task is an object which manage threads and code. For a beginner like user2840469 it is enough to know that his code runs at the same time as his other code.